# Tools to compress images to pagespeed standard

Tags: image-processing, pagespeed, image-compression, google-pagespeed

I've been using Photoshop's "Save for web" option to save images that go on my website.

I keep the quality level at 60 which reduces picture quality slightly. When I increase the level pagespeed tells me that the images can further be compressed without loss.

I've also tried to do the same with Irfan View which has batch resize and compress which is great but results in the same pagespeed warning.

What can I do here? Is there any other tool I can use?

Comment: How about a sample, troublesome image to see what you mean?

Comment: @MarkSetchell https://imgur.com/a/0Ng5V has been saved by Photoshop at 60 quality but pagespeed tells me it can further be reduced by 38KB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is 182kB as you posted it. With **ImageMagick**, you could down-sample the chroma and reduce the quality like this for 144kB:

```
convert ZtUUpS8.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:2 -quality 75 result.jpg
```

[image]

Or, you could say you want an image no larger than 90kB like this:

```
convert ZtUUpS8.jpg -define jpeg:extent=90KB result.jpg
```

[image]

You can copy each of those and try them before installing ImageMagick :-)

---

Batch Processing

Make a back up of your files first and work on a **COPY** of a small subset until you get the idea.

If you are on Windows, and you want to do batch processing, you have two options:

#### 1. Use ImageMagick's `mogrify` command:

```
mogrify -define jpeg:extent=90KB *.jpg
```

#### 2: Use Windows' `FOR` loop

I don't use `Windows`, but there is a FOR loop described [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), that would look something like this:

```
FOR /F %%G IN (*.jpg) DO convert "%%G" -define jpeg:extent=90KB "%%G"
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I checked these images on pagespeed and it says that it still can be reduced slightly, but that's okay. Now, is there something similar but with a GUI and batch processing that I can use to do the same?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some suggestions for batch processing. Sorry, I am not best on Windows.

Comment: Thank you Mark :)